# Youtube API V3 : YouTube livestream resolution in "variable" doesn't detect 1080p

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are using the **YouTube API V3** to create/retrieve livestream and stream with **RTMP**.

When a live is created from the API and the *cdn.resolution* is set to 1080, everything is great. The viewer can see **1080p**.

But when the live is scheduled from the Studio, the retrieved live has "resolution": "*variable*" settings.
According to the documentation: *"Use this setting to indicate that YouTube should automatically detect the resolution of your streamed video. You must also set cdn. frameRate to variable."*

But when a 1080p video is sent to the stream, the viewer cannot see it in 1080p. At best, 720p.

I've thought about updating the *cdn.resolution* before starting the live, but according to the documentation: T*he API does not allow you to change the value of the cdn. format, cdn. frameRate, cdn.
ingestionType, or cdn. resolution fields after the stream is created*

Any advice to have 1080p even with scheduled live ?

Thanks